# count number of divs with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a little confused as to how to get an accurate count of the number of divs containing a certain class.  Because of the DOM here , I can't use `.parent()` or `.child()`  and `.length` and `.size()` aren't going to be able to work unless I find a way to specificy where to start counting and where to stop

example

```
<div class="container">
      <h2 class="12345">title<h2>
      <div class="_row">...</div>
      <div class="_row">...</div>
      <div class="_row">...</div>
      <h2 class="6789">title<h2>
      <div class="_row">...</div>   //count these
      <div class="_row">...</div>   //count these
      <div class="_row">...</div>   //count these
      <div class="_row">...</div>   //count these
      <div class="_row">...</div>   //count these
      <div class="_row">...</div>   //count these
      <h2 class="01234">title<h2>
      <div class="_row">...</div>
      <div class="_row">...</div>
      <div class="_row">...</div>
      <div class="_row">...</div>
      <div class="_row">...</div>
   </div>
```

so if my function got 6789 passed into it , I would want the count of div's containing class "_row" after ".6789" but stop the count at the next `<h2>`  .

I am kind of lost here because they are in the same level in DOM , So I can't do `$('.6789' > '._row')`      or `$('.6789').parent().find('._row);`   if anyone could help with getting the accurate count that I need it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you might want to look into [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/). There's actually an example on that page that is almost exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @MrOBrian, you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [jQuery's nextUntil() function](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/). The linked page has example code that does almost exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can start at the h2 element and select all the following div by use of the [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) like this:

```
var countOfDivs = $("h2.6789").nextUntil("h2","div._row").length;
```

The second argument to nextUntil ensures that the selection is stable in the case the markup starts to include other elements than div._row between the h2 elements